# How to convert a UNC device path to a file URI?

Tags: windows, windows-11, path, unc, uri

I have `\\?\UNC\localhost\Volume{59e01a55-88c5-411f-bf0b-92820bdb2548}\`, which I need to convert to a `file://` URI. I also need to use `%SystemDrive%` in place of the `Volume{}` identifier, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Device paths are somewhat more complex than regular UNC paths, so I'm having difficulty. I've checked the other answers on this forum, but none of them appear to be directly applicable to *device* UNC paths.